# How to attach rundeck execution log for sending via curl?

Tags: webhooks, rundeck

I'm developing a script on rundeck, sending custom webhooks.

But I am not able to send the log of the work execution itself.

I need the execution log to be sent in the message body.

As in the example:

Log rundeck:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0k8R.png)

I need this log to be in the body of the message, I've tried some ways but it didn't work, does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-notification) plugin using the plugin manager, the plugin is for sending HTTP notifications against any node.
2. In your command step/script step use the multiline data capture filter (to capture all the output in a single data variable like `${data.mydata}`).
3. Now using the global variable step, take the data value (the job output) and create a global variable to export across the job or use in notifications, e.g: `${export.tonotify}`.
4. In your job (creating or editing), go to the `Notifications` tab, select any scenario (e.g: `On Success`), clic on the `+ Add Notification` button, select the "Http Notification" on the "Notification type" list, then put the HTTP URL, `POST` method and `${export.tonotify}` on body section.

Take a look at this Job definition example for [testing](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions):

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: fdda4e33-9121-4119-9685-69a18a0e1989
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  notification:
    onsuccess:
      plugin:
        configuration:
          authentication: None
          body: ${export.tonotify}
          contentType: application/json
          method: POST
          remoteUrl: https://your/url/to/post
          timeout: '30000'
        type: HttpNotification
  notifyAvgDurationThreshold: null
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: 'Any command / script / wathever, the ouput is captured by multiline
        regex data capture filter'
      exec: ls -a
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            hideOutput: 'false'
            logData: 'true'
            name: mydata
            regex: ^(.*)
          type: key-value-data-multilines
    - configuration:
        export: tonotify
        group: export
        value: ${data.mydata*}
      description: create an export variable to notofy or use acroos your jobs
      nodeStep: false
      type: export-var
    - description: just for debugging
      exec: echo ${export.tonotify}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: fdda4e33-9121-4119-9685-69a18a0e1989
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyszT.jpg) (I used [webhook.site](https://webhook.site) to test).